# Got a downvote for an answer on a question that's deleted

Tags: discussion, downvotes, automatic-deletion

I recently got an alert for a downvote (44 minutes back). But when I click on the question I see that it's been deleted. And it seems like it's quite old, as I don't remember when I answered or what I answered.

How can I view this question or what actually happened?

And this is the link I click on the question: [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416213/jpa-how-to-do-it/16416374#16416374)

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: You need 10k rep to view deleted questions, I don't have that either on SO to be able to look at it but my guess is that the question was closed and the only reason it wasn't auto-deleted previously was because your answer had an upvote. That automatic process (the Roomba) ran about 20 minutes ago and once your answer had a score or zero the question would have been eligible for deletion.

Comment: Note, you're now going to lose another 8 reputation when it's recalced...

Comment: Yep got the alert for another -8 on same question.

Comment: @Joe - What was the reason for HB to lose 8 additional reputation points?

Comment: @Kevin - Too lazy to upload another image. But the other -8 was for the question being removed in total -10 was done, which is counter to +10 for the upvote I received for this question. Joe correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I meant.  Which indeed happened: notice the rep was 1716 then, and is now 1718, with a +10 from a different question in between - meaning he's net lost another -8.  That -8 isn't actually shown, though, because the question went away - it's just gone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two ways I would recommend when trying to view a deleted question when you have less than 10k.

1. Go to archive.org and type the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in the [Wayback Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine).
   ***or***
2. Go to google.com, type the URL (*stackoverflow.com/questions/16416213/jpa-how-to-do-it*) and then if it comes up, don't click on the usual link, but click on the down arrow to the right of it, and it should drop down the option for ***Cached*** version. Click on that.

---

**This is the question:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**This is your answer:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

So like [@PeterJ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/got-a-downvote-for-a-question-thats-deleted#comment108622_275018) said, the question must have been auto-deleted during the daily cleanup. The downvote you received would have put that answer to a score of 0, thus making the question eligible for the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/244519).

Comment: Thanks, forgot about the archived pages.

Comment: Another way is to gain 10K rep. My personal favorite.