# Link to Wayback Machine or original site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When linking from within the SE network to an external site, is it preferable to go to archive.org and archive a link, then use the archive.org link in a question/answer/comment?

Of course, the upside of this is that the link doesn't (or is less likely to) rot, and all context, information, etc. at the time of the post is maintained. The downsides I can see are:

1. Author of the linked page may not receive recognition/ad-revenue/views/whatever
2. The linked page may be updated with new information, this becomes a little harder to find

Edit: As per my comment below I'm going to add a feature-request: Could SE send a request to archive.org to archive links as they're posted? You can do this in your browser by visiting (for example): https://web.archive.org/save/http://stackoverflow.com. This way, it's possible to have people post original links but to maintain the linked content as it stands at the time of submission. Someone else might know whether archive.org rate-limits requests (though I'll have a look now).

Comment: Assume archive.org is volatile, even if it isn't really volatile. The answer/question/link's contents should be stand-alone on Stack Overflow, so that even if everything but Stack Overflow were taken offline when Skynet takes over, the answer will still be useful as we attempt to beat it back with compiler errors.

Comment: Of course, as you know, this is already the policy. However, I often wonder what's better and whether anyone has a good argument for preferring one or the other.

Comment: IMO, if you are including the link, then link to the original source.

Comment: @bluefeet Any specific justification? Same as I've listed? Upon further examination, perhaps the ideal course of action is to link to the original source, but make an entry in the WayBack machine at the time of posting.

Comment: Isn't this like putting all your eggs in one basket?

Comment: This is a good point. If you *replaced* all external links with links to the Internet Archive, yes. But, I think my later feature request *increases* redundancy: SO extracts all externally linked URLs and passes those URLs to the internet archive, but does *not* change the URL of the question/answer/comment. That increases redundancy by backing up the externally linked material, as now Internet Archive has a copy of the original content. Most importantly, this means someone who finds a dead link later has a reasonably high expectation of finding the original material at the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 2):

**For internal links**

I don't think you should be linking to the archive.org link under most circumstances. I see no point in that especially if the question/answer your linking to is not deleted. Even in cases where a post is deleted, you probably still should just be using the regular SE link. Users with 10k and more and mods can always view the deleted content.

The only time I'd suggest linking to the archived link is if a user specifically asks for help viewing a deleted post or you think the archived link will be very helpful for him/her at *this moment* in time.

Even when users are asking questions on meta about why a post was deleted, you should probably still just use the regular SE link and post a screenshot yourself of the deleted post or ask for a 10k'er to provide one.

Plus, if a user wants to find the archived page, they can already do that themselves. There's been [questions answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/got-a-downvote-for-an-answer-on-a-question-thats-deleted) here on meta about how to do it already. So just having the original SE link is fine enough, since they can use the Way Back Machine themselves to see the archived screen shots.

**For external links**

Pretty much the same as above. Answers within SE should be self containing. So even if a link rots it should be no big deal. If a user wants to see an archive of the external link they can look it up themselves. Use the original link. If say you run into a post that is a useful answer and you notice the link rotted I see no issue with leaving a comment to the archive link.

Comment: I suspect you may have partially misunderstood my question. I meant external links, not links within SE. I've clarified in the question.