# How to handle links to external resources like grepcode or docjar (or the OpenJDK repository)?

Tags: discussion, external-links

I'd like to know whether there is a general policy when it comes to links to external resources that are essential for the credibility of the answer.

For example, answers in the style of

> `ArrayList` had an initial default capacity of 10 in Java 6, as can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList), but has a default capacity of 0 in Java 7, as can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList).

When these links die, the answer may still be considered as being helpful, but the *references* are important in order to verify that the answer is actually correct. Simply copying the relevant code snippets from these classes would not help to assert any provenance in this regard (and might raise copyright issues in the worst case)

Should one rather omit links like these, and leave the statement as it is, relying on the upvotes as an indication for the correctness of the answer?

If not: Are there any "preferred" sites to link to for these cases? Particularly, can grepcode or docjar be considered to be durable enough to be worth being linked to from stackoverflow? Or should one prefer links to the OpenJDK repositories? (And probably even edit existing answers with such links accordingly?)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284186/3001761

Comment: After the answer has been vetted for a year or more, the supporting evidence disappearing isn't exactly very important anymore.  It just needs to be updated for Java 8 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost anything that isn't spam can be validly linked to from Stack Overflow, if done properly. It's not that we hate links - it's just that it's important to ***also* cite content** from inside the link, so that if the link does die at some point, the essential info (the reason the link is relevant) isn't lost. In your example, this would be the fact that in addition to the link, the writer also notes the relevant default value that they're citing in each linked resource. As long as that's been done, there's absolutely nothing wrong with linking to any high-quality, relevant off-site resource as an additional reference for someone who wants to read more than the excerpt you're citing.

Comment: I see (although there probably is no clear-cut border: If the answer had been "The capacity has changed between 6 and 7, as can be seen `here` and `here`", people would probably consider it as a "link only" answer). **But**: I don't want to boil this down to the question of "how much content has to be cited". An important aspect of my question was referring to the *credibility* and the *authority* of the answer by giving a definite (durable) *reference*. I think that the OpenJDK repositories *could* be considered to be such an authoritative reference. For grepcode etc., I'm not so sure...

Comment: I think the answer to the question you're asking, then, is just going to be that there isn't really such a policy. The more durable and "official" a source the better, but that isn't really codified anywhere and it's often going to be a subjective judgement call. Any link might break, so providing useful citations is a much more clear-cut and enforcable policy to codify.

Comment: *"Any link might break"* - except for links to stackoverflow :) But I see the point. Link rot is a general problem, and one can only try to do the best by linking to resources that are "unlikely" to die soon and by quoting the parts that are most relevant for the question - and hope that the potential upvotes from people who visited the links while they were still working serve as an indication for the credibility for the time after the links died.