# Should the verifiability of a quotation be called into question when the link breaks?

Tags: discussion, broken-link

Every now and then, we get custom flags reporting broken links in answers that are decidedly *not* link-only because the content is present in the answer either as a quotation, or in the author's own words. Something like

> According to [this article]:
>
> > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

where "this article" is an actual link that has broken.

Our usual response to this is "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention", because broken links are something that anyone can attempt to fix on their own, without requiring any mod-only abilities.

But lately I've been wondering... what if said link can *not* be fixed, for example because the linked page was not crawlable and therefore never indexed on the Internet Archive, and no other mirrors or alternative sources exist of it? What happens to the text? Do we assume the quotation was accurate at the time of posting, or should the text be considered "no longer verifiable" or something and the post as a whole link-only (if there is no other original content)?

The reason I ask this now is because I just encountered a flag in which the user said the broken link made the whole answer useless despite the content being right there in the answer, which made me wonder if by "useless" they meant "no longer verifiable", because otherwise literally dismissing the entire thing as useless seems excessive to me...

Comment: BoltClock wearing a suit now, fancy, new job?

Comment: Whoever flagged Pekka's comment as too chatty clearly isn't crazy 'bout a sharp dressed man^H^H^H clock.

Comment: BoltClock, that reference just made you one of my top three mods. Just saying.

Comment: This question worries me.  Has SO sunk *that* low that you can't trust an answer anymore that's been vetted for years by thousands of programmers?  Nah.  No.

Comment: Remotely related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290620/how-to-handle-links-to-external-resources-like-grepcode-or-docjar-or-the-openjd (regarding the "credibility" aspect and verifiability...) and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284186/link-to-wayback-machine-or-original-site

Answer (score 13):

Well if the (presumed) main content of link is included and comprehensive enough for an answer, I don't think there's any action that a moderator can take that we as a community can't already.  I would personally just edit the post with a edit note that the link is now broken and give as much attribution as possible.  For example, you might be able to glean some author information from the previously working link.

> According to [Someone's] article previously posted on [some website]:
>
> > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

And at the bottom, where links are typically organized, I would just leave a comment that the link is broken.

```
[1]: http://previouslyWorkingLink.com <!-- link now broken -->
```

Pros:

- It retains attribution to the original source as much as possible.
- The link could potentially be fixable in the future, and then it's easy to just add it back into the post.
- The link can't be navigated to from the post in case it become reactivated by someone other than the original source (like spammers).

Cons:

- This is kinda like the `//TODO` comments I sometimes forget to clean up in my code.  It can make future edits more cumbersome.

Answer (score 9):

My thought is that if they give enough information that someone interested enough could search around, test, etc... and try to verify themselves then I'm not sure it would be much different than an answer like,

> Try this, it may help you...
>
> some codez >

**But the author has gone deep, deep underground**

Even if it's original research that no creature alive can find another source to anywhere, if it's still giving enough substance for someone to verify the content by trying or looking into more then I don't see the difference.

Example

> I've found through my research, [linked here](http://www.example.com/) that you can not foo a bar without a whatchyamadoodle. I have done these tests and there is not enough foo power without a whatchyamadoodle.

then you should have enough details to verify that for yourself and so it could still be valuable to others. The question that answers is probably slightly off topic in some way but you get what I mean.

However, like anything else, there will be exceptions. If the contained information isn't enough for someone to reasonably reproduce it then it should probably be fed to the wolves. Though, in that case, it would probably be a link only answer to begin with and the mods would have already struck it down.