# Automated link archiving

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Too many times I find a years-old post with a solution to a problem where someone in the comments below the answers links to a very helpful page with more information, details, etc; only to click and find the link is dead.

I propose we add automated link archiving to comments, so that when a url is commented, it is presented like this:

[google.com](https://google.com) <sub>[[archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20190812181134/https://www.google.com/) | [live]](http://google.com)</sub>

Or something similar. Which auto archives either with a public archive service's API, or with a custom StackExchange scraping solution that would be developed.

Comment: Related analysis I did 4 years ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them

Comment: @Andy very glad to see data backing this up, I felt it was a large amount but 10% is more than I had thought!

Comment: [Related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284186/link-to-wayback-machine-or-original-site).

Comment: Is the `|live` part necessary? The link is already lincluded in the primary text, there doesn't seem to be a need for anything more than `[archived]`

Comment: @Zoe might be good to just do archived. I think in my mind I added live to emphasize the difference or optionality of the whole thing, but I am a fan of "less is more"

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I really like your idea and I would not restrict it to comments only. Also the links in questions and answers should be preserved automatically imo.

Comment: @Thomas If the archive link is in a separate `[archived]` part of the text, and the main text contains the original URL, `|live` is redudant. Following the example in the question, the link in the `google.com` text and the `live` text points to the same link. Only `archived` points elsewhere